# Is there an AI service that could be used to classify 30,000 different tools and parts?

Tags: neural-network, classification, image-classification, image-recognition

I'm trying to build an image classifier where people can take a picture of a tool or part and have the image classified. Much like bixby or amazon's tool to do something similar, but with only 30,000 different items to classify instead of a huge shopping catalog.

I was hoping there would be an AI service that takes a lot of the work out as I am trying to avoid training my own CNN because the manpower necessary to take the amount of pictures I would need is not achievable for my project. I can definitely get the manpower to take some pictures, to the tune of maybe 300,000 to 1 million, but I don't believe that would be enough while training a brand-new CNN.

Answer (score 1):

Use pre-trained models and transfer learning.

take **keras** as example:

https://keras.io/applications/

you just need prepare dozens of pictures for each category and can have a pretty good performance.